# C# Adding watcher to Jira isse via JSON and REST API

Tags: c#, json, jira

I have a syntax issue with my JSON string when attempting to add a watcher to an existing Jira issue, but I can't figure out what it is.

```
string URL = "http://jira/rest/api/2/issue/TS-1000/watchers"
string JSON = @"{{""watchers"":[{{""name"":""jdoe""}}]}}"
```

When I submit the JSON via POST to the URL I get `BAD REQUEST 400` and `The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect`

I've run the JSON through a validator and it came out fine.  I've also tried different things like "username" instead of "name", more quotes around the username like `""""jdoe""""` which will produce `""jdoe""` when it's submitted, etc but nothing seems to make a difference.

Elsewhere in the program I'm able to create and close Jira tickets - so I know my HTTPREQUEST and Authentication code is fine (hence why I didn't post it.)

I've researched the problem and there's a lot of examples for CURL, but that's not very helpful for me.

Comment: Shouldn't the Json be `@"{""watchers"":[{""name"":""jdoe""}]}"`?

Comment: Well, for the sake of brevity I condense the code in my initial post.  The full line is this:  `string addJiraWatcher = string.Format(@"{""watchers"":[{""name"":""{0}""}]}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["theboss"]);`


But I get the exception `Input string was not in a correct format.` when I use that string.  :/

All my other JSON queries that I've used in this manner need the curly braces doubled up.  But I've output the string to a label and the double quotes and braces are removed - so I assume that's how it's submitted in the webrequest.

Answer (score 1):

You need to double `{{` only when you use such string as parameter to `String.Format`. So if you want to send just constant string use single curly braces like ` @"{""watchers"":[{""name"":""jdoe""}]}".

Note that it would be better to use JSON serializer to produce valid JSON. Usually JSON.Net is good choice:

```
 var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
         new {watchers = new []{new {name = "jdoe"}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this will not work this is a long standing bug see here.
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-29304

You will have to change to using 
https://yourInstance.com/rest/api/2/issue/{IssueId}/watchers

Data would be your verified user enclosed in double quotes 
"""myuser.lastname"""

"""myuser.lastname""" https://yourInstance.com/rest/api/2/issue/{IssueId}/watchers

This is different than most of the other requests and drove me nuts for a few hours.  I am using .net and I had to format the user name with the quotes and pass that into a method that wraps an HTTPWebRequest.  I use a simple method to push the data into the request.getRequestStream.

```
public string RunIt(string queryString, string data = null, string method = "GET")
{
string uriString = string.Format("{0}{1}", m_BaseUrl, queryString.ToString());
Uri uri = new Uri(uriString);
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(uriString) as HttpWebRequest;
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Method = method;
if (data != null)
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        writer.Write(data);
    }
}
string base64Credentials = GetEncodedCredentials();
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", Convert.ToString("Basic ") + base64Credentials);
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NoContent)
    return "204";
string result = string.Empty;
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    result = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
string URL = "http://jira/rest/api/2/issue/TS-1000/watchers"
string JSON = @""jdoe""
```

The JSON format for this request is a bit weird. In order to add a watcher with this API request **the JSON body needs to be just the Jira user name as a quoted string**.

You can see this specification in [the API's documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v2/#api-rest-api-2-issue-issueIdOrKey-watchers-post).
[Add watcher Jira API specification circled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ta5Zf.png)

I recently had to figure out this little puzzle when trying to add watchers through the Jira API using a C# script. Below is the function I ended up using inside my script ->

```
public static void assignWatcher(string issueKey, string watcher, JiraServerInfo JInfo)
    {
        var client = new RestClient(JInfo.JServerName + "rest/api/2/issue/" + issueKey + "/watchers");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + System.Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JInfo.JUsername + ":" + JInfo.JPassword)));
        request.AddParameter("application/json", "\"" + watcher + "\"\n", ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
    }
```